# ILoggerProvider - one gets config, the other does not (or gets the other)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, ilogger, iloggerfactory

This is really strange. [I have a simple example here.](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/bdwwcazwqvn4pcgtfazv1/Blazor_Logger_bug.zip?rlkey=g27gdzvp4ehg8zy3fwc573oez&dl=1)

---

Please note in the sample (linked above) I have:

```
public BlobLoggerProvider(BlobLoggerOptions options)
{
    Options = options;
    Options = new BlobLoggerOptions
    {
        Path = "log/{yyyy-MM-dd}.txt",
        Interval = "day",
        AzureStorage = "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    };
    Interval = GetInterval(Options.Interval);

    Start();
}
```

This is setting explicit values for the Options so the system will run. The bug is the passed in parameter `options` has null values for all properties.

---

I have one ILoggerProvider that works perfectly (in Blazor server). Defined as:

```
[ProviderAlias("File")]
public class FileLoggerProvider : LoggerProviderBase
{
    protected FileLoggerOptions? Options;

    public FileLoggerProvider(IOptionsMonitor<FileLoggerOptions> options) : this(options.CurrentValue)
    {
        SettingsChangeToken = options.OnChange(opt => { Options = opt; });
    }

    public FileLoggerProvider(FileLoggerOptions options)
    {

        Options = options;
        Interval = GetInterval(options.Interval);

        Start();
    }
```

The other is defined as follows:

```
[ProviderAlias("Blob")]
public class BlobLoggerProvider : LoggerProviderBase
{
    protected BlobLoggerOptions Options;

    public BlobLoggerProvider(IOptionsMonitor<BlobLoggerOptions> options) : this(options.CurrentValue)
    {
        SettingsChangeToken = options.OnChange(opt => { Options = opt; });
    }

    public BlobLoggerProvider(BlobLoggerOptions options)
    {
        Options = options;

        Start();
    }
```

This second one passes in a `BlobLoggerOptions` with all properties set to null.

And even weirder - if I change it to have a `FileLoggerOptions` as the options passed in - it does populate that with the "File" properties from appSettings.json. Event though it has `[ProviderAlias("Blob")]`.

Any idea what can be causing this? I've tried a ton of different things, all to no luck.

Below files in case they're helpful:

appSettings.json:

```
"Blob": {
    "Path": "logs/{yyyy-MM-dd}.txt",
    "Interval": "Day",
    "AzureStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
},

"File": {
    "Path": "C:/temp/{yyyy-MM-dd}.txt",
    "Interval": "day"
},
```

Properties files:

```
public class FileLoggerOptions
{
    public string? Path { get; set; }
    public string? Interval { get; set; }
}

internal class FileLoggerOptionsSetup : ConfigureFromConfigurationOptions<FileLoggerOptions>
{
    public FileLoggerOptionsSetup(ILoggerProviderConfiguration<FileLoggerProvider> providerConfiguration)
        : base(providerConfiguration.Configuration)
    {
    }
}

public class BlobLoggerOptions
{
    public string? Path { get; set; }
    public string? Interval { get; set; }
    public string? AzureStorage { get; set; }
}

internal class BlobLoggerOptionsSetup : ConfigureFromConfigurationOptions<BlobLoggerOptions>
{
    public BlobLoggerOptionsSetup(ILoggerProviderConfiguration<BlobLoggerOptions> providerConfiguration)
        : base(providerConfiguration.Configuration)
    {
    }
}
```

And how I add them:

```
public static class LoggingBuilderExtensions
{
    public static ILoggingBuilder AddFileLogger(this ILoggingBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.AddConfiguration();

        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider,
            FileLoggerProvider>());
        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IConfigureOptions<FileLoggerOptions>,
            FileLoggerOptionsSetup>());
        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IOptionsChangeTokenSource<FileLoggerOptions>,
            LoggerProviderOptionsChangeTokenSource<FileLoggerOptions, FileLoggerProvider>>());
        return builder;
    }

    public static ILoggingBuilder AddAzureBlobLogger(this ILoggingBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.AddConfiguration();

        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider,
            BlobLoggerProvider>());

        /* switch to this to get the "File" properties
        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IConfigureOptions<FileLoggerOptions>,
            FileLoggerOptionsSetup>());
        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IOptionsChangeTokenSource<FileLoggerOptions>,
            LoggerProviderOptionsChangeTokenSource<FileLoggerOptions, BlobLoggerProvider>>());
        */

        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IConfigureOptions<BlobLoggerOptions>,
            BlobLoggerOptionsSetup>());
        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IOptionsChangeTokenSource<BlobLoggerOptions>,
            LoggerProviderOptionsChangeTokenSource<BlobLoggerOptions, BlobLoggerProvider>>());

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to move `builder.AddConfiguration();` out of the `AddFileLogger` and `AddAzureBlobLogger` methods and ensure that `builder.AddConfiguration();` is only loaded globally once.

Comment: You can try enabling only FileLogger or only BlobLogger to see if it works well. Because I suspect that after enabling them together, the configuration may have been reset.

Comment: @JasonPan I did try enabling just one - File worked, Blob did not. And enabling both - File worked.

Comment: Hi David, I downloaded your repo and test it in my local ? [It works fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtfOi.png) I didn't change any thing, you also could replace the connection with azure storage account for testing.

Comment: @JasonPan Did you break in the constructor for `BlobLoggerProvider`. Because just after that I have code to hardcode the options so it runs.

Comment: Hi David, I just download it and run it, not change anything.

Comment: @JasonPan I just updated the issue - please read the new explanation at the top. Yes the example will run - **because** I hardcoded the options after they come in null.

Comment: Hi David, I have double check your repo and find the issue. Will share the solution below, thanks for your patience and will reply your other threads later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BlobLoggerProvider` in below method, not `BlobLoggerOptions`. And please check the test result first.

[image]

```
// copyright (C) 2023 by David Thielen. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
// This code is confidential and is only to be viewed and/or used by authorized individuals & entities.

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Blazor_Logger_bug.Loggers
{
    public class BlobLoggerOptions
    {
        public string? Path { get; set; }
        public string? Interval { get; set; }
        public string? AzureStorage { get; set; }
    }

    internal class BlobLoggerOptionsSetup : ConfigureFromConfigurationOptions<BlobLoggerOptions>
    {
        public BlobLoggerOptionsSetup(ILoggerProviderConfiguration<BlobLoggerProvider> providerConfiguration)
            : base(providerConfiguration.Configuration)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On my computer [the BlobLoggerOptions are all null](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/amer9aw4myufzsub4ypun/BlobLoggerOptions.png?rlkey=1ub475278fuh2di3bhrt2sboo&dl=0). Running the same program. How is that possible? Also, thanks for digging in to this.

Comment: Hi @DavidThielen have you follow my suggestion to modify your code, I believe it’s a typo, you should compare it with my screenshot.

Comment: Hi @DavidThielen, check my screenshot, left area , it’s different with yours. I have found the RCA

Comment: You are my favorite person in the world today. Thank you!!! (A developer I respect a lot often says that the single largest source of bugs is cut & paste errors.) Again, thank you.

Comment: Hi @DavidThielen, I also follow your another thread in Q&A, pls check it. Happy coding