# net: Implementing custom Configuration Provider with support of reload/refresh

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration

I'm writing custom configuration provider for `net6.0` and greater, extending `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationProvider`. I have implemented `Load()` method (calls remote source, tokenize to configuration key-value and saves dictionary to `Data` property) - quite straightforward implementation.

Now I'm thinking about improving implementation to better support `IOptionsMonitor<T>` and `IOptionsSnapshot<T>`, but I can't find any documentation describing this in detail. My configuration source doesn't support push mechanism, so the best I can do is polling. (Though with bigger effort, push could be achieved too)

There are methods like `GetReloadToken` and `OnReload` but I'm struggling to understand who's caller of those and what's life time of options (respectively its configuration source).

How all this work? What's the process for reloadable configuration source?

```
internal sealed class MyLittleConfigurationProvider : ConfigurationProvider
{
    private readonly ConfigFetcher _configFetcher;

    public MyLittleConfigurationProvider(IDataClient client)
    {
        _configFetcher= new SecretsFetcher(client);
    }

    public override void Load()
    {
        var config = _configFetcher.GetConfig().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var data = // turn config to dictionary

        Data = data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IOptionsMonitor` like below. If you modify the settings in `appsettings.json`, it will detect the change.

```
public class FileLoggerProvider : LoggerProviderBase
{
    protected FileLoggerOptions? Options;

    public FileLoggerProvider(IOptionsMonitor<FileLoggerOptions> options) : this(options.CurrentValue)
    {
        SettingsChangeToken = options.OnChange(opt => { Options = opt; });
    }

    public FileLoggerProvider(FileLoggerOptions options)
    {

        Options = options;
        Interval = GetInterval(options.Interval);

        Start();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override QueueWriterBase CreateQueueWriter()
    {
        var filenamePattern = Options?.Path ?? "log-{yyyyMMdd}.txt";
        var logPath = filenamePattern.FormatWithDate(DateTimeKind.Utc);
        logPath = Path.GetFullPath(logPath);
        return new FileQueueWriter(logPath);
    }
}
```

Please check the repo in this thread, there have detailed code. And  it has some issues I have fixed it, you also need to check my answer. Then you will know how to use it.

[ILoggerProvider - one gets config, the other does not (or gets the other)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77291164/iloggerprovider-one-gets-config-the-other-does-not-or-gets-the-other)

Comment: Hi @jason-pan, I'm afraid it didn't click for me. What I'm really missing is that part of modifying source and getting event to every `IOptionsMonitor<T>` used. In my case, detecting that source data has changed (e.g. config in DB/remote storage/...) means doing periodical polling - if new value differs from current value, update config provider and let all option monitors know about the change. I couldn't find link to repo you mentioned, so I'm still missing full picture.

Comment: @Zdeněk [link is in the post I shared](https://uc1651ce37b937d2e47e463ecc72.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/CLeLyse8l9Z4Yv_2MhT5iX-i84lLW9O2Jymkyzv-5viyQdeYOq-BD2XKX_u_ISlAwGVpdqYzdF2lLeH_hzWLxaNztVCcpurvwPS-RuA4Iwfgvh1s2yNgfa29A70xcpf27aIL-XHNVoHiVwYtlsHo9r8-/file?dl=1#), you can click it for checking

Comment: seems that dropbox has issues with this file. Would you mind creating Gist or Git repository? (That's anyway better than downloading .zip files ¯\_(ツ)_/¯); Apart of that, I found this blog post https://mousavi310.github.io/posts/a-refreshable-sql-server-configuration-provider-for-net-core/ which explains some parts of process I was struggling with.

Comment: Hi @Zdeněk [Click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77291164/iloggerprovider-one-gets-config-the-other-does-not-or-gets-the-other) and click the link like the picture. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC3S1.png

Comment: Hi @Zdeněk The repo I shared in the link is a better way to use it, you can refer to it.

Comment: @Zdeněk Please let me know if you need further help.